# How can I compute the expected value and variance of the 4th power of the sample median?

Tags: expected-value, bias, unbiased-estimator, median

Given the following parameter estimate, how do I find $E[\hat{a}_{MED}]$ and $Var[\hat{a}_{MED}]$?
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:Estimator_a_Med}
    \hat{a}_{MED} = - \left( n_0 \right)^4 \cdot \log(0.5)
\end{equation}

where $n_0$ is the sample median.

The density function is: $$f(x) = \frac{4a}{x^5} \exp \left[ {- \frac{a}{x^4}} \right] \quad \text{for} \quad  0 \leq x \leq \infty, \ a>0$$
having a CDF
$$F_X(z) =  \exp \left[ {-\frac{a}{z^4}} \right]$$

Comment: It depends on the details, so please tell us the nature of your data, your distributional assumptions about them, and provide a few summary statistics.

Comment: I have added the PDF and CDF to my original question.

Comment: Is this an exercise/assignment etc for a class?

Comment: Specifically now that we see the distribution, there's a simple thing you're probably supposed to do that should make the work simpler, a classic sign of a homework exercise

Comment: If it's not homework, it might help to explain the context (which often gives valuable clues about different ways to approach the underlying problem you're attempting to solve). Are you interested in small-sample results or asymptotic approximations?

Comment: This is part of a uni assignment as i was required to formulate some estimator of a using an order statistic (here i chose the median). I was successful in constructing a simulation to see how this estimator will act, however I wish to determine if there is a general equation for finding its Expected value and variance, rather than just being limited to that of the simulation.